# Не работает атрибуты у текста

Tags: svg

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300" width="400" style='border:1px solid black'>
  <text x='50' y='150'font-size='120' fill='red' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' text-decoration='underline overline line-through' font-weight='100' font-style='obligue' font-stretch='ultra-expanded'>
    Простой текст
  </text>
  <!-- <path d="M0,250 A100,100 0,0,0 500,250" /> -->
</svg>
```

1. Не работает font-stretch='ultra-expanded'
2. Не работает font-style='obligue'

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300" width="400" style='border:1px solid black'>
  <defs>
    <style>
      text{
        font-style: obligue;
        font-stretch: ultra-expanded;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <text x='50' y='150'font-size='120' fill='red' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' text-decoration='underline' font-weight='100' font-style='obligue' font-stretch='ultra-expanded'  unicode-bidi="bidi-override" glyph-orientation-vertical="0" font-size-adjust="1.1" dominant-baseline="hanging">
    Простой текст
  </text>
  <!-- <path d="M0,250 A100,100 0,0,0 500,250" /> -->
</svg>
```

Comment: вынесите все стили в defs style

Comment: @MaximLensky изменил ничего

Comment: поддержку проверяли ?

Comment: extra-expanded в хроме не поддерживается

Comment: @MaximLensky у меня ultra-expanded а не extra-expande :)) а как свойство font-style: obligue; ?

Comment: может быть тоже не поддерживается

Comment: @Leks,как-то так, https://caniuse.com/#search=font-style

Comment: @Node_pro  поддержку в svg не увидел

Comment: я не знаю как это выглядит - ни чего сказать не могу

Comment: поддержка у svg  это просто то что умеет браузер

Comment: @Leks, Разницы нет, CSS то один.

Comment: кстати мы всегда можем сделать - текст в svg path